# How to partially update the DOM using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views

My HTML is as follows:

```
<div id="spotPrices">
    <label class="spotLabel">Oil (WTI) $/bbl:</label>
    <INPUT type="text" id="OilSpotPrice" Size=8>
</div>
```

and my JavaScript:

```
ShowSpotPrices = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        wti: "0.00",
    },

    url: function () {
        return 'http://localhost:4000/api/getSpotPrices';
    },

    initialize: function () {
        console.log("Initialized ShowSpotPrices Model...")
    }
});

ShowSpotPricesView = Backbone.View.extend({
   el: '#spotPrices',
   initialize: function() {
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'sync change', this.render);
        this.model.fetch();
        this.render();
   },

    render : function() {
        //this.$("#OilSpotPrice").html("27.45");
        this.$("#OilSpotPrice").html(this.model.get('wti'));
        return this;
    }
});

var spotPrices = new ShowSpotPrices();
spotPrices.fetch({
    success: function (model) {
        console.log("New spotPrices model fetch: " + model.get('wti'));
    },
    failure: function (model) {
        console.log("Failed to fetch spotPrices model");
    }
});

var spotPricesView = new ShowSpotPricesView({model: spotPrices});
console.log("After spotPricesView.render: " + spotPricesView.model.get('wti'));
```

I am able to successfully fetch the `wti` value using the API endpoint.

However, I am unable to update `#OilSpotPrice` using jQuery. I have tried both updating with a fixed string value and also using `model.get()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the **value** of the `#OilSpotPrice` input using the [`.val()` jQuery function](http://api.jquery.com/val/), not its inner HTML.

```
this.$("#OilSpotPrice").val(this.model.get('wti'));
```

Also, you could limit to one jQuery `find` call in the `initialize` method.

```
initialize: function() {
    // cache the jQuery object of the input once
    this.$oilSpotPrice = this.$("#OilSpotPrice");

    this.listenTo(this.model, 'sync change', this.render);
    this.model.fetch();
    this.render();
},

render : function() {
    // then use the object
    this.$oilSpotPrice.val(this.model.get('wti'));
    return this;
}
```

Comment: Thanks again my friend.  That is exactly what I was looking for.  The cache is a nice touch as well.